# Can I combine several types in ColumnListItem SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

[Mock-up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxzCH.png)
I want to create table which looks like this. I have problem with buttons in the right side of row. I find that I can add it separately using Table mode="Delete" and ColumnListItem type"Detail" and "Navigation". Is there some way to combine it? Now I use buttons in column to achive that.

[Buttons realization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcWBA.png)

Comment: No way to combine them. For what it's worth, I've used the same approach as you have, combining buttons like that